# Elasticsearch searching all fields containing a value?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 1000,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "wildcard" : {
          "_all" : "*tunnel*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to execute a query to search all fields containing the phrase `tunnel`. I have titles called tunnel.xml and get no results. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Query String Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

```
GET data/Company/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*tunnel*"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can construct this with the Java API?

Comment: @JohnLippson this should work `import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;
QueryBuilder qb = queryStringQuery("*tunnel*");`